# Java inheritence with different typed variables

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

with the code below is there a way to make these two extremely similar classes inherit from a single superclass? they differ almost exclusively in variable types. If not is there a design pattern that seems most appropriate for this case? I've been looking at maybe using a factory pattern but I'm not sure if that's the most appropriate for the situation.

```
class stringCharacteristic {
    String name = "";
    String value = "";

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public stringCharacteristic setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public stringCharacteristic setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

class intCharacteristic {
    String name = "";
    int value = 0;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public intCharacteristic setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public intCharacteristic setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

edit:
Found a solution that works reasonably well for my purposes using generics, probably not the most efficient but it gets the job done. Also, I know the code looks a bit off with the fluid interface and everything, that's not the code that I'm actually writing just a simplified thing to show the issue without copy-pasting a hundred lines of stuff that just distracts from the main issue.

```
class characteristic<E> {
    String name;
    E value;

    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public characteristic<E> setValue(E value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public characteristic<E> setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public characteristic<E> setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
        return this;
    }

    public characteristic<E> setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd be looking for generics, something like `NamedWrapper<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

No(t really).

You have two fundamental issues here.

### Primitives don't play the dynamic typing game.

If you have e.g. a `StringCharacteristic` (note that in java we `WriteTypesLikeThis`, not `likeThis`) and a `LocalDateCharacteristic` it's all object refs and we can generalize over that, make a supertype `ObjectCharacteristic<T>`. But, generics can't be primitive, and there is no way to generalize over primitives.

Right now, that is. Project Valhalla is seeing a ton of active development (I'm pretty sure it sees, by a large margin, the most effort amongst all the various language-related projects in active development at OpenJDK right now), so keep a weather eye on your JDK update's feature lists.

You can work around it by using the wrapper type (`java.lang.Integer`), but this is a very poor substitution: They can be `null` which is annoying (`int` cannot be), and they are an order of magnitude less efficient both CPU and memory wise. They also aren't necessarily compatible - autounboxing only goes so far.

You'd shove these methods in a superclass (make it package private if you don't want to make that aspect of it a part of your public API), using generics: `class Characteristic<T>`, using `T` instead of `int`/`String` everywhere in that superclass, and then that superclass can just be the thing. If you really insist on having an explicitly named type, you can just write `public class IntCharacteristic extends Characteristic<Integer> {}`, maybe add a constructor, and call it a day, the rest is taken care of (even the field, which you'd declare in the superclass as `private T value`.

But, that gives you a characteristic class that uses `Integer`, and not `int`. There's no way to have it use int. Not until valhalla.

If you aren't willing to accept that inefficiency, you're going to have to manually write out the `int`-related bits.

### The problem of the self type

This secondary issue does not show up if you both accept the negative aspects of using `Integer` instead of `int`, *and* you're okay with just having a single `public class Characteristic<T>`, with no custom subclasses.

The problem with a type hierarchy and 'fluent API' (API methods that return their own type) is that they **do not work here**.

### Interlude - let's write it.

Because the name bits are the exact same, except for the return type of the setName method, we can do this:

```
private abstract class Characteristic {
    private String name;

    public Characteristic setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And then you can write subtypes of this, and you can just skip all the code for the name stuff, as your superclass takes care of that:

```
public class IntCharacteristic extends Characteristic {
    private int value;

    public IntCharacteristic setValue(int value) {
     ...
    }
}
```

### But, problem!

The one issue here is that the setName method has the wrong return type. Yes, it returns `this`, and `this` would, in the case of a new `IntCharacteristic` instance, be `instanceof IntCharacteristic`, but your `setName` method's return type doesn't declare it, and thus javac won't treat it as such. Thus, this will **FAIL**:

```
new IntCharacteristic().setName("Hello").setValue(5);
```

You can make it succeed, using a self-generics hack.

**This is a bad idea, and you need to read on for a much better solution**. I include it here because whilst in this case there is a better solution available, sometimes there is not, and this hack IS the best solution:

```
public class Characteristic<S extends Characteristic<S>> {
    private String name;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected S self() {
        return (S) this;
    }

    public S setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return self();
    }
}

public class IntCharacteristic extends Characteristic<IntCharacteristic> {
}
```

This code ensures that the return type of `setName` **is** `IntCharacteristic` which is what you want. It is **impossible** to make this work without a cast that causes the compiler to emit a warning that the operation doesn't actually do any checking at all, but we know it's going to be 'true', because that weird signature (`S extends Self<S>`) effectively means that anything that extends it can only put itself in the `<>`.

### Much better solutions

Mostly, that whole 'return self' thing is overblown. It's not particularly java-esque, and this shows how it causes issues. More generally, if you insist on making 'modern' API, then it's like you've built a kitchen with a medieval oven and a brand new microwave next to each other. The modern take involves immutability. Why do you even allow name to change here? Shouldn't it be set in stone upon creation? Then you avoid this entire mess!

```
public class Characteristic {
    private final String name;

    public Characteristic(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class IntCharacteristic extends Characteristic {
    private final int value;

    public IntCharacteristic(String name, int value) {
        super(name);
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Problem solved.

### Stop returning self, by the way

Fundamentally, `return this;` is not a good idea except possibly in `final` classes. The problem is that *clearly* your intent is merely to make it easy to 'chain' method calls to this thing, but fundamentally **this cannot work** if hierarchies are involved, unless you use the above hack which cannot be 'hidden' (that generics param is part of your public API now).

You're also not really using it to return the result of a calculation, which is what return values are intended to do.

In other words, you're hacking the language when you do this. There are reasons to do so, but it's best to do so with open eyes: Whenever you hack around the language you're going to have to deal with the fact that eventually it'll bite you in the arse.

The *REAL* solution is either for java-the-language to grow the concept of 'self type', or better yet, for java-the-language to grow the concept of 'allow chaining'. The MUCH better solution to this problem is one of these 2 true solutions:

### Language proposal A

```
chainable public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Where the `chainable` keyword both requires (compiler error if not) that the return type is `void`, AND it lets callers write `new Foo().setName("stuff").chainMoreMethodsHere();`. It's purely `javac` syntax sugar, none of this survives in the class file other than as a marker so `javac` knows what to do. THe method's signature in the class file keeps its VOID return type, and language tools know that e.g. ignoring the return type is completely fine here.

### Language proposal B

Leave it in the hands of the callers instead of in the API writer:

just have a void method: `public void setName() { ... }`, but the caller can choose to chain:

```
Foo x = new Foo()..setName()..setSomethingElse();
```

here the double dot means: Invoke the method, toss away whatever is returned, and resolve the expression to be identical to the receiver. (`x.foo()` means: call `foo`, toss return type, expression resolves to `x`).

Currently there is no traffic in OpenJDK lists about any of this. But maybe today is different. If ever this is added, your API is now broken and probably will feel outdated forever more.

I'm not saying fluent APIs are utterly idiotic. But close to it. You're hacking the language and usually, either because of the self type thing or future language improvements, that means you'll regret it someday.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how useful this is depends on what the client wants to do with instances of `Characteristic`, that is when it can't tell what concrete class they are.

If there are cases where (for instance) you want to show the names of a set of `Characteristic`s, and perhaps a `toString` of their values, then this will be useful.

You can do this:

```
interface Characteristic<T> {
    public T getValue();
    public String getName();
    Characteristic<T> setValue(T value);
    Characteristic<T> setName(String name);
}

class StringCharacteristic implements Characteristic<String>{
    String name = "";
    String value = "";

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public StringCharacteristic setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public StringCharacteristic setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

class IntCharacteristic implements Characteristic<Integer> {
    String name = "";
    int value = 0;

    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public IntCharacteristic setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public IntCharacteristic setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

(Please use correct Java naming conventions by the way)

You can use an abstract class to factor out the common implementation:

```
abstract class AbstractCharacteristic<T> implements Characteristic<T> {
    String name = "";
    T value;

    public AbstractCharacteristic(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Characteristic<T> setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Characteristic<T> setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

class StringCharacteristic extends AbstractCharacteristic<String>{

    public StringCharacteristic() {
        super("");
    }
}

class IntCharacteristic extends AbstractCharacteristic<Integer> {

    public IntCharacteristic() {
        super(0);
    }
}
```

(We need the constructor parameter because a String field would normally be initialised to `null` by default, rather than `""`)